# Builder design pattern in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, json, node.js, design-patterns

Need to construct a custom JSON file after parsing XML. To cut the long story short, have an XML file from which must be  created a JSON file, but not all information from XML must be present in JSON. It must be done using only  JS and Node.js. To parse XML I used xmldom and fs.

Now the part I am stuck at. To create a JSON file I can't use code snipped already available on the Web, because there are very few examples with Node.js and because I need to omit many things from XML. Looping also is not a possibility, since XMLDOM is recursive. Right now I use this code to do it:

```
  var builder = function() {
    this.meta = {};
}

builder.atRoot = function(library) {
    this.meta["!name"] = library;
    this.meta["!define"] = {};
    this.define = this.meta["!define"];
}


builder.atNamespace = function(name) {
    this.namespace = {};
    this.namespace["!category"] = "namespace";
    this.namespace["!description"] = "";
    this.define[name] = this.namespace;
}

builder.atDescription = function(method){
    this.class = {};
    this.class["!Accordion"] = method;
    this.class["!AccordionSection"] = method;
    this.class["!ApplicationHeader"] = method;
....


}

// and so on

builder.toJson = function() {
    var s = JSON.stringify(this.meta);
    console.log(s);
}
```

But it doesn't work. Now, may be I simply don't understand how builder works, or it is the wrong way. Any ideas on what is wrong, or additional explanation of builder design pattern will be much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please specify, what "doesn't work" mean? What is expected result and what is actual one?

Comment: @kirilloid function 
builder.toJson = function() {
    var s = JSON.stringify(this.meta);
    console.log(s);
}

doesn't print the result of the code above. In debug mode it doesn't even go inside it. Expected result is something like this:
["!category"] = "namespace"
["!description"] = "" etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Builder` usually implies recursion. I don't fully understand what do you need, but it seems that you need to create a whitelist of attribute names and just recursively copy properties into new object, then serialize it as JSON.

Comment: Yes, something like this. I will try it, thanks.
I basically need to create from XML file with JS methods a JSON file with the same methods, so the latter can be used by linter to show hints.

Comment: Many thanks, your suggestion helped. I moved on with this task.